# Extract numbers from a string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column in excel that looks like this:

```
Census Tract 2941.10 (part), Carson city, Compton CCD, Los Angeles County, California
Census Tract 5410.02, Carson city, Compton CCD, Los Angeles County, California
Census Tract 5431 (part), Carson city, Compton CCD, Los Angeles County, California
Census Tract 5432.02 (part), Carson city, Compton CCD, Los Angeles County, California
Census Tract 5433.04, Carson city, Compton CCD, Los Angeles County, California
```

I need to extract 2941.10, 5410.02, 5431, etc...
I tried the following formula: `=MID(E4,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(E4,ROW($3:$606),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(E4,ROW($3:$606),1)))`

However, the decimal in the middle of the number makes it so the last two numbers are cut off. Not all numbers have a decimal, and the amount of text after the number varies by row (so left and right formulas are not options). 
I must use an excel formula and not VBA/macros.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use "Text to Columns"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
=--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),2*999,999),",",""))
```

[image]

---

The formula above assumes that the numbers are always the third "word" in the text.  If that is not the case ***AND*** there is only one group of number per string, you can use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)*999+1,999),",","")),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

It iterates through the words and returns the sum of all the numbers group, and since there is only one number group it returns just that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**    I deleted my first answer as I realize that you probably want to return a string of digits, **including** leading or trailing 0's, and it is at least conceivable that the digit string might be longer than 15 digits.

So the formulas below return the number as a text string, preserving any leading and trailing zero's.  e.g `2941.10`is returned as such, and not as `2941.1`

Here is one formula solution

First define `seq` as a Named formula:

```
seq Refers To:  =ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))
```

`seq` will return an array of numbers `{1...255}`  Unlike the `ROW(INDIRECT(...` method of returning arrays, this formula is non-volatile.

Then you can use this array formula entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
=MID(A1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,seq,1)),0),LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,seq,1)),seq)-MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,seq,1)),0)+1)
```

or, you can used this slightly longer but normally entered formula:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")),LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,seq,1)),seq)-MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)
```

If it is the case, as in your example, that the digit sequence **always** starts in the 14th position, then you can use this simplified, normally entered formula:

```
=MID(A1,14,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,seq,1)),seq)-13)
```

[image]